# Is it possible to transfer money without Internal TXNs?

Tags: solidity, evm

Exactly what I want is this:

I'm transferring money to a contract. The money coming into this contract will be forwarded to the destination address without creating any TXN (that is, anonymously).

I created a contract and the money sent to this contract is sent to the target wallet. In this way, information does not appear in Transaction transactions of the target wallet.

**the code i use**

```
     receive() external payable {
        payable(0x8162Ac860EF729d60C0f3683bfaA0334A3499956).send(msg.value);

   }
```

**As pictured (see Transactions)**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPxH5.png

- **So far everything is ok. But there is one problem. Transaction appears in Internal TXNs. I want to hide this.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/39nCh.png

What should happen: Money will be transferred to the contract and it will transfer money anonymously without generating any TX belonging to the target wallet.

**REQUIRE --->>** When the money sent to the contract is sent to the counter wallet, no information will appear in the Transactions and Internal TXNs tab of the counter wallet.

- Is it possible to do this? Please tell me what should I do if
  possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.  Any transfer of a native chain token (BNB in your case of Binance Smart Chain) will appear on an explorer like Etherscan (Bscscan) as an "internal transaction".